# Rouche's Theorem for $h(z)=z^5+3z-2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Using the theorem if $f(z)$ and $(g(z)$ are analytic on and inside the contour $C$ and $|f(z)|>|g(z)|$ on C, then $f(z)$ and $f(z)+g(z)$ have the same number of zeros. I want to find the number of zeros of $h(z)=z^5+3z-2$ that lie within the unit disk $D_1(0)$.

I tried $f(z)=3z-2$ and $g(z)=z^5$, and

$$|f(z)|=|3z-2|\ge||3z|-|2||=|3-2|=1$$

and

$$|g(z)|=|z^5|=|z|^5=1^5=1$$

So I do not have $|f(z)|>|g(z)|$. Then I tried $f(z)=3z$ and $g(z)=z^5-2$, and

$$|f(z)|=|3z|=3|z|=3$$

and

$$|g(z)|=|z^5-2|\le|z^5|+|-2|=1+2=3$$

so again, I don't have $|f(z)|>|g(z)|$.

I'm stuck. Suggestion? And, there are many different forms of Rouche's Theorem, but I want to use the one I posted up at the top.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your second method works if you consider the disk of radius $r<1$ in stead of the unit disk: $r^{5}+2 <3r$ for $r<1$, $r$ close enough to $1$. Hence the number of zeros of $h$ is $1$ for all such $r$. Letting $r$ increase to $1$ we can conclude that $h$ has exactly one zero.